# using link_to inside if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user_authenticate method which is setting the @current_user based on session. I have a navbar layout which contains the navigation links. I want to hide one of the links and show it only if user id is 8 (which is admin). I have written the layout like this.

```
<div align="center" style="width: 90%">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <%= link_to "Home", '/', :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <%= link_to "Currency Master", currencies_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <%= link_to "Receipts", receipts_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <%= link_to "Expenses", expenses_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <%= link_to "Exchange", exchanges_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <% if @current_user.id == 8 %><%= link_to "Report", reports_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

The code works fine that it shows the "Report"button on navbar only of the user id is 8. But as soon as I click on the link I get following error.

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #8):
6
7
8
9
10

  <%= link_to "Expenses", expenses_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <%= link_to "Exchange", exchanges_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn"%>
  <% if @current_user.id == 8 %><%= link_to "Report", reports_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you please add full error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not check if the user is an Admin by ID. You can have an "is_admin" column of boolean type and check like this:

```
if @current_user.is_admin?
# ...
```

Second, before check the value of a column, you can check first if the object itself exist. So your if condition can be like this:

```
if @current_user && @curent_user.is_admin?
   # show admin menu
else
   # show other menus
end
```

Comment: I like your solution as it would also give me options to create more than one admin but when I try it as below

Comment: I like your solution as it would also give me options to create more than one admin but when I try it as below 

`<% if @current_user && @current_user.is_admin %><%= link_to "Report", reports_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
  <% end %>
</nav>`

I get following error

**undefined method `is_admin' for #<User:0xd69ae08**

Comment: @Parry sorry the delay. This is because you dont have this column. You need to create a migration to add this column with boolean type

Comment: wow! this worked. I realized I created a Boolean column as ádmin' so I modified it to `if @current_user && @curent_user.admin?` and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `@current_user.id` even if `@current_user` is not present. so it is giving an error.

**First check the presence of current_user and then check id,**

**`@current_user.present? && @current_user.id == 8`**

Change this line,

```
<% if @current_user.id == 8 %><%= link_to "Report", reports_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
  <% end %>
```

to,

```
<% if (@current_user.present? && @current_user.id == 8) %><%= link_to "Report", reports_url, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: @Parry, have you checked this?